# Typescript const assertion readonly reverse

Tags: typescript

With TS const assertion, is it possible to 'undo' readonly for particular values.

eg:

```js
export const UlOpts = {
  defaults: {
    margin: ['0', '0', 'm'],
    padding: ['0', '0', '0', 'm'],
  },
} as const
```

translates to:

```js
const UlOpts: {
    readonly defaults: {
        readonly margin: readonly ["0", "0", "m"];
        readonly padding: readonly ["0", "0", "0", "m"];
    };
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the below output instead? (readonly has been removed from the arrays):

```js
const UlOpts: {
    readonly defaults: {
        readonly margin: ["0", "0", "m"];
        readonly padding: ["0", "0", "0", "m"];
    };
}
```

I have tried the below, (which works) but seems a little verbose, is there a better way?

```js
export const UlOpts = {
  defaults: {
    margin: ['0', '0', 'm'] as ['0', '0', 'm'],
    padding: ['0', '0', '0', 'm'] as ['0', '0', '0', 'm'],
  },
} as const
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense - if you want to specify that the array contains exactly those elements in that order, then mutating the array is not typesafe.

Comment: The problem i'm facing is that i then want to assign these values as default values in a function which is giving me the error The type  is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type

Comment: Post about your *real* problem (the problem you have with the function) instead of what you think you need to do to force it to work. What does the function look like and what are you trying to do with the data structure there?

Comment: The `const UlOpts = ...` assignment *already* assigns the values. If you want to assign different values later then they will no longer be `['0', '0', 'm']` - but the type annotation will still **say** they are `['0', '0', 'm']`, so the type annotation will be violated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically convert a type to a version of itself where any properties or nested properties which are readonly arrays have become mutable arrays, you can do that with mapped conditional types like this:

```
type DeepMutableArrays<T> =
    (T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: DeepMutableArrays<T[K]> } : T) extends infer O ?
    O extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? { -readonly [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : O : never;
```

Then you could make a generic identity function which takes a value of type `T` and returns the same value but asserted to be of type `DeepMutableArrays<T>`, assuming that any arrays or array properties or nested array properties you pass in really are mutable at runtime:

```
const asDeepMutableArrays = <T>(x: T) => x as DeepMutableArrays<T>;
```

Then you could define `UlOpts` like this:

```
const UlOpts = asDeepMutableArrays({
    defaults: {
        margin: ['0', '0', 'm'],
        padding: ['0', '0', '0', 'm'],
    },
} as const);
/* const UlOpts: {
    readonly defaults: {
        readonly margin: ["0", "0", "m"];
        readonly padding: ["0", "0", "0", "m"];
    };
} */
```

And you can see that the type of `UlOpts` is exactly what you asked for. It's a bit confusing why you want that in this case, though, since the only thing you can assign to a non-readonly tuple of string literals is the particular string literal that it presumably already contains:

```
UlOpts.defaults.margin[2] = 'm'; // okay but... why?
UlOpts.defaults.margin[2] = '0'; // error, can't change it from 'm'
```

If you maybe wanted to widen the tuples from `readonly ["0", "0", "m"]` to something like `["0"|"m", "0"|"m", "0"|"m"]` or `[string, string, string]` or `string[]`, that would be a (slightly) different question with a (correspondingly slightly) different answer.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAqgGwPIAcoSQJwJYHMYC8MA3gLABQMVMAJgKYBmAhgK4LoBcJF1vMAtk0y5sYLgG0A5AAZJAGhgz5i-pIC6cnnyoomNGqNwSlCk4tmnVGrVQC+m8rZhMIMUJCgBuColToseAB09Mxs6IGCwqLiAExqhCqSnjAA9CkwdJiYIJgK2FCSrph0euAIAJ4UFFDlKHQwACJ0dCgAsixQTABGCHQAgllM5RAAPAAqAHyENjAAFGMZAB5QdGA0riBdAFZ0wLAA-CQw4gDSMKIwANZ05SAMMGNqXE0t7Z09-YPD46dqU05cMYASiWKzWrlEDEyMCQMH2M1hdGWq3WMAASiUaGVygNMEMRkwwOUpodiDAALTFUpgCrHM4Xa63e5IJ4w34wAEwmBcMB0ABumW85AoaRgtxYbhAbBoMAA7jgVs4YAwWGA9thwDAoCBaDqmHsWEwEJKUOVDM5YJhVVBsPx6th7uK5YSoBQVWqbZr6K8Ot1erihqNJrNFoCgc9mm1fR8A99JkL3eqvZG3n7PnjhiGuITyiCyJRqA65jU6ncYIsYABCAhEABEmx2e1rMAAPi3y4QazAwGwECDilAWJgwOWhbwi7NY4FsBBYyGgXmZrx3NAYAPs0TxPEiFux9py4EGDkAKL6gAWsz5hCmA8CKBYEAv3qj739Xwgl4XQL32gHQ5HA4-hyMwrpadBQBu5QJMQthAUg2y7FAgSMh+ixAoeJ7nrMlzXmu4HiJc260Cm0ZvhmqEEWoC5AX+w54V4FC2FU5Cil0HRKvexS0iWdDkr0ArGgKmAQBqI4zjAKDZF0fpQQwoj2iO-AgKuwAuHQEAUKBzgQC8L5prGrhEOMExZg8IIEFMFYuI0JGvumgbGUKmngKuvhoIZ2m6amMbvrM+a8CErDsBAXD+fukQiGIxxmDFVgOPuEl6AYYBGNFFjmMosXqPF1D2Ix2mSh434igAVIVrnIO5oUzFSWI0lBgVhCF3AFr+mLYgIQiRRItbSLWCi9f1MC1vwtZqEBvC1R1uj6IYPV9QNC3DUtI1jUBsH5SVKTMSuIC9IECAgLgsxuegQI+JV4SNcFERddEcQJJIqjJKKICXEMMBsUhgSBHKZ7lPC5CnRAwSMEF4QRfdRFKC96SZNkuRuISkiwMAZ6Erg9qwAw2T8IkFBAA)